# XCode7.3 keep crash when I enable breakpoint to debug

Tags: crash, breakpoints, xcode7.3

It will not crash when I debug without breakpoint, once enable a breakpoint, XCode will debug to that line of code, then immediately crash。
It crash at thread 22 as bellow:

```
Thread 22 Crashed:: <DBGLLDBSessionThread (pid=838)>  Dispatch queue: DVTInvalidationPreventionQueue
0   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000118e3d986 clang::ASTContext::getFunctionType(clang::QualType, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::QualType>, clang::FunctionProtoType::ExtProtoInfo const&) const + 294
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a139964 lldb_private::ClangASTContext::CreateFunctionType(clang::ASTContext*, lldb_private::CompilerType const&, lldb_private::CompilerType const*, unsigned int, bool, unsigned int) + 542
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119fb290a DWARFASTParserClang::ParseTypeFromDWARF(lldb_private::SymbolContext const&, DWARFDIE const&, lldb_private::Log*, bool*) + 9830
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a120e68 SymbolFileDWARF::ParseType(lldb_private::SymbolContext const&, DWARFDIE const&, bool*) + 184
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a11b108 SymbolFileDWARF::GetTypeForDIE(DWARFDIE const&, bool) + 368
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a11ab21 SymbolFileDWARF::ResolveType(DWARFDIE const&, bool, bool) + 129
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119fb7ff9 DWARFASTParserClang::CompleteTypeFromDWARF(DWARFDIE const&, lldb_private::Type*, lldb_private::CompilerType&) + 1165
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a11aedc SymbolFileDWARF::CompleteType(lldb_private::CompilerType&) + 628
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a1a59cb lldb_private::Type::ResolveClangType(lldb_private::Type::ResolveStateTag) + 1483
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a1a5c74 lldb_private::Type::GetFullCompilerType() + 26
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a0007da lldb_private::ValueObject::MaybeCalculateCompleteType() + 352
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a000568 lldb_private::ValueObject::GetCompilerType() + 18
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a1c680a lldb_private::Process::IsPossibleDynamicValue(lldb_private::ValueObject&) + 64
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a005bca lldb_private::ValueObject::CalculateDynamicValue(lldb::DynamicValueType) + 90
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011a005c6f lldb_private::ValueObject::GetDynamicValue(lldb::DynamicValueType) + 65
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000117ff51dd ValueImpl::GetSP(lldb_private::ProcessRunLock::ProcessRunLocker&, lldb_private::Mutex::Locker&, lldb_private::Error&) + 243
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000117fef90a lldb::SBValue::GetSP(ValueLocker&) const + 58
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000117fef9f9 lldb::SBValue::GetName() + 41
18  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x0000000117f3ad75 -[DBGLLDBDataValue initWithLLDBValueObject:forStackFrame:withParent:updateSummary:] + 234
19  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x0000000117f3ac29 -[DBGLLDBDataValue initWithLLDBValueObject:forStackFrame:withParent:] + 92
20  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x0000000117f38370 -[DBGLLDBStackFrame _findSymbolWithName:symbolKind:atLocation:] + 1070
21  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x0000000117f38748 __93-[DBGLLDBStackFrame requestDataValueForSymbol:symbolKind:atLocation:onQueue:withResultBlock:]_block_invoke + 60
22  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d08dfb4 ___DVTPreventInvalidationForObjectAllowingRecursiveCallsDuringBlock_block_invoke_2 + 49
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8491b40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8492c5a4 _dispatch_sync_f_invoke + 56
25  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d08df54 ___DVTPreventInvalidationForObjectAllowingRecursiveCallsDuringBlock_block_invoke + 150
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8491b40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8492c5a4 _dispatch_sync_f_invoke + 56
28  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d08dda3 _DVTPreventInvalidationForObjectAllowingRecursiveCallsDuringBlock + 383
29  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d08e10d _DVTPreventInvalidationAllowingRecursiveCallsDuringBlock + 35
30  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x0000000117f37b80 __45-[DBGLLDBStackFrame _addSessionThreadAction:]_block_invoke + 108
31  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x0000000117f50755 -[DBGLLDBSession handleNextActionWithState:withRunPending:] + 457
32  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x0000000117f4aca5 DBGLLDBSessionThread(void*) + 2089
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8dc4599d _pthread_body + 131
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8dc4591a _pthread_start + 168
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8dc43351 thread_start + 13

Thread 22 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
```

Answer (score 1):

Include a setting **CLANG_ENABLE_MODULE_DEBUGGING = NO** stopped the crash for me.